React-Native-Video does not work with Expo (Android)
ScreenShot is Here ! ! ! 
I also installed react-native-video 5 but I had same problem . Message from expo go :
"RCTvideo was not found in the UIManager" . => i need this feature just for text track ability
and other plugins

Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block.

Hi @omid, were you able to resolve this ?
